# Unable to get Taleo entity picklist values

Tags: rest, taleo

I am working with Rest API's of Taleo Business edition. I am unable to get picklist values using Discovery API. For example if i try to get picklist values for 'status'field of Requisition using Rest API  `https://ldn.tbe.taleo.net/ldn01/ats/api/v1/object/displayfield/REQU/status` 
then in response i get blank value for 'lookupValues'

```
{
    "response": {
        "displayfield": {
            "status": {
                "entityType": "REQU",
                "displayFieldName": "Status",
                "externalName": "status",
                "dataType": "Picklist",
                "description": "",
                "maxLength": -1,
                "sortedAscending": false,
                "selectFirstAsDefault": false,
                "fieldType": "L",
                "lookupValues": []
            }
        }
    },
    "status": {
        "success": true,
        "detail": {}
    }
}
```

Any idea what i am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Taleo is weird. For some values it returns picklist e.g. https://ldn.tbe.taleo.net/ldn01/ats/api/v1/object/displayfield/WORK/role but for some, the similar API returns blank response.